# Write a AZERTY to QWERTY converter

Tags: code-golf, string

Your task is to create a program will transform each letter of a text typed on a AZERTY keyboard to the equivalent on a QWERTY keyboard, using the same keystrokes.

Example: `Hello; Zorld1 => Hello, World!`

List of character to convert:

- `A <=> Q`
- `Z <=> W`
- `, => m`
- `? => M`
- `M => :`
- `1 => !`
- `9 => (`
- `; => ,`
- `§ => ?`
- `0 => )`
- `) => -`
- `ù => '`

QWERTY keyboard:
[image: QWERTY keyboard]

AZERTY keyboard:
[image]

Test cases:

```
Input: This is q text zritten zith q QWERTY keyboqrd:
Output: This is a text written with a AZERTY keyboard.

Input: Hello zorld in PythonM print9ùHello; Zorld1ù0
Output: Hello world in Python: print('Hello, World!')

Input: Zikipediq is q free online enciclopediq
Output: Wikipedia is a free online enciclopedia

Input: Progrq,,ing puwwles qnd code)golf
Output: Programming puzzles and code-golf

Input: Zhy ,y lqyout hqve szitched to QWERTY §
Output: Why my layout have switched to AZERTY ?
```

This is code golf, so the answer with the shortest byte count win.

Comment: Could you please explicitly list which character should be replaced by which?

Comment: @flawr Every character, i'll add this

Comment: He means an explicit list. Like, `A => Q`, `W => Z`, etc.

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg Can you please add that list?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? This has a fixed substitution set, the other has a variable one!

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ it would seem that valid answers to that challenge would  work for this one with minor changes then. So I would agree that it is a dupe. HOWEVER, the other challenge has a lot of restrictions that this one does not. One might argue that this challenge is open to entries from more languages which would be in favor of reopening.

Comment: @Liam I second this; the other one is **harsh**! You can vote to reopen this, comments do not vote by themselves!!!

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, <strike>70</strike> 132 bytes

My first try in code-golfing, so please be kind :):

```py
print(input().translate(str.maketrans('azqwAZQW&é"\'(-è_çà)^$Mù,?;:!§1234567890','qwazQWAZ1234567890-[]:\'mM,./?!@#$%^&*()')))
```

[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/tInNSi)

Comment: ; is converted to m, and numbers should also be handled. Oh and put your code in a code element (\`code\`), not a blockquote ;)

Comment: Should be better now :).

Comment: you can prolly save with a lambda instead of `print/input`.

Comment: `ValueError: the first two maketrans arguments must have equal length`

Comment: No such error on my local installation. I have just added a 'try it online' link.